# Customisable timesheet and invoice software

Tags: project-management

I am supporting the management of a new project with a high number of externally contracted staff that we need to collect timesheets and expenses for. To avoid the administrative hassle of everyone submitting different style timesheets, I'm looking for recommendations and comments on the most appropriate customizable timesheet/expense management software for my needs.

See below:

Essentially what I have in mind (ideally) is an online platform where all our externals can be given login details and sign in weekly (or whenever) and populate their timesheets and expenses against specific budget lines. Each person that logs in will be able to assign time against specified budget lines that the PM has assigned to that individual external (avoiding the risk of the external being able to allocate time against an budget line they are not assigned to). Ideally then, the PM (or whoever is managing the timesheets) will be able to monitor and manage each externals time allocations.

I would be very grateful of any comments, ideas etc.